# Increasing spacing between tips and tip labels on a phylogram in phytools?

Tags: r, visualization, phylogeny

I'm new to R and having trouble increasing legibility of a phylogram I made with phytools for my dissertation. As you can see, the tip nodes partially obscure the tip labels, so I'd like to add more space between them. I tried reducing the size of the tip nodes, but this decreases their visibility too much.

[image: Phylogram]

My code:

```
plotTree(eel.tree,type="fan",fsize=1.1,ftype="i")
nodelabels(node=1:eel.tree$Nnode+Ntip(eel.tree),
           pie=fitORF$lik.anc,piecol=cols,cex=0.5)
tiplabels(pie=to.matrix(feed.mode,sort(unique(feed.mode))),piecol=cols,cex=0.2)
add.simmap.legend(colors=cols,prompt=FALSE,x=0.9*par()$usr[1],
                  y=-max(nodeHeights(eel.tree)),fsize=0.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `plotTree` from the `phytools` package internally calls a function `plot.phylo` from the `ape` package. That means that you can explore plotting options in `?plot.phylo`.

The argument `label.offset` will increase the space between tree tips and its labels:

> label.offset
> a numeric giving the space between the nodes and the tips of the phylogeny and their corresponding labels. This option has no effect if type = "unrooted".